# How would I join a list of tuples in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples and I would like to create tuples of 3 numbers by joining the tuples in every possible unique combination.

ex.

```
old_list = [(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]

new_list = [(2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)]
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why isn't `(3,4,5)` or `(2,4,2)` in your list?

Comment: Do you want to get all the unique combinations of elements from those three lists?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to get all the unique combinations of those three tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inferring that the first item in your `old_list` tuples can only be first items in your `new_list` tuples, and that the second items in your `old_list` tuples can only be second and third items in your `new_list` tuples.

```
import itertools

old_list = [(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
oldlist0 = [a[0] for a in old_list]
new_list = list(itertools.combinations(set(a for b in old_list for a in b),3))
new_list = [a for a in new_list if a[0] in oldlist0 and a[1] not in oldlist0 and a[2] not in oldlist0]

new_list

Out[21]:
[(2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5)]
```

Comment: This was the line I was looking for. Thanks! 
new_list = list(itertools.combinations(set(a for b in old_list for a in b),3))

Answer (score 0):

use `itertools` for flattening and permutation? (and lots of mapping)

```
import itertools

old_list=[(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
new_list=list(itertools.chain(old_list))

print map(list,map(set,list(itertools.permutations(zip(*new_list)))))[0]
```

Comment: I think you should give the output.  Who knows if that is what the OP wants?

Comment: Crap, test didn't yield right output. Editing